# Where clause with case statement and variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Creating SSRS report with a parameter in which the user can select accounts with a balance greater than or equal to zero.  Within my Select statement I have

```
, payment1 + payment 2 + payment3 + invoice AS CurrentBalance
```

And in my Where I have

```
and (case when @Balance = 1 then (payment1 + payment2 + payment3 + invoice) end > 0
   or
     case when @Balance = 0 then (payment1 + payment2 + payment3 + invoice) end = 0)
```

This kills my performance.  Whats an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
AND (
  (@Balance=1 AND payment1 + payment2 + payment3 + invoice > 0)
OR
  (@Balance=0 AND payment1 + payment2 + payment3 + invoice = 0)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I normally hang out in the VBA SO, so SQL sometimes gets the best of me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This kills my performance. Whats an alternative way to do this?
Maybe...

```
having (@Balance = 1 and currentBalance > 0) OR (@Balance = 0 and currentbalance = 0)
```

I'm not sure if it has to re-do the math twice each time in the where clause which this may prevent..

Another alternative would be to add a computed column to the table so the payments1,2,3+invoice math is already done.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about using HAVING but wanted to keep my where clause similar to other reports we have out there to things simple, also, I'm not in the position to alter tables but thanks for reply, something to keep in mind in the future.